# Android Dev, Is it possible to sense all touch event in android OS

Tags: android, android-service, gestures, android-intentservice

Looks difficult from my search.
If it is possible, how should I implement?

Comment: A `Service` doesn't have a UI. Why not use an `Activity` ?

Comment: I need to catch them when my activity is not in front...